# select all keys with given value

Tags: json, path, slice, jq

With `jq`, how do I select all objects, which may be nested, with a desired value?

For example, given the following:

```
{
    "a": "b",
    "c": {
        "d": {
            "e": "f",
            "z": "b"
        }
    }
}
```

How do I filter down to objects whose value is `"b"`?

```
{
    "a": "b",
    "c": {
        "d": {
            "z": "b"
        }
    }
}
```

Conversely, how do I select objects whose value is **not** `"b"`?

```
{
    "c": {
        "d": {
            "e": "f"
        }
    }
}
```

---

I've attempted at the problem by using the `select` and `walk` functions, but could not get exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I see someone has voted to close your Q . To avoid the Q being closed, I'd suggest showing the attempts you've made to solve each problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question:

```
reduce paths(. == "b") as $p ({}; setpath($p; "b"))
```

For the second:

```
reduce paths(. == "b") as $p (.; delpaths([$p]))
```

or even more succinctly:

```
delpaths( [ paths(. == "b") ] )
```

### Furthermore

The first question can also be answered without `reduce`, but to get it right generically requires more verbosity, e.g.:

```
delpaths( [ paths( (. !="b") and (type|IN("object","array") | not) ) ] )
```